# Session Handling if page is .html in Spring

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Could you please clarify whether we can handle the session properly If I use .html pages instead of .Jsp pages in Spring MVC, whether there is any difference between these two, I am using the Angular JS also,so if I call Ajax calls from HTML page, whether it would be possible to track the session. Could you please guide me, thanks

Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you can't track session as JSP's. 
But using cookie concept you can store sessionID and pass that session id on all subsequent rest calls and verify the sessionID against stored backend sessionID.
Once the user logged out clear the sessionID from backend session and clear the cookie. If no cookie found ask the user to login/authenticate

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

HttpServletResponse response = //
response.setHeader("JSESSIONID", session.getId());
```

Another approach is, with spring security
When you authenticate an user with spring security it will store userID/username in security context and you can configure your security to authenticate all the specific rest URL's

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/url").authorizeRequests();
}
```